# Creating URL from String(with encoding)

Tags: ios, swift, url, encoding, nsstringencoding

I am trying to create URL from String like the following

```
let searchParam = "?name=movies&Genre=#Action"

func searchMovies(searchString: String) {
    let encodedString = searchParam.encodeSearchString()
    let urlString = "https://search.movies.local/list.html" + encodedString

    guard let url = URL(string: searchParam) else {
        return
    }

    print("URL: ", url)
}

func encodeSearchString() -> String? {
  let unreserved = "#?=&"
  let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
  allowed.addCharacters(in: unreserved)
  return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed as CharacterSet)
}
```

It works fine when the search param is "?name=movies&Genre=#Action" but if the search param contains more than one #, then the URL is nil.

For eg., if the searchParam is "?name=#movies&Genre=#Action"

Comment: Use URLQueryItems instead: `var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString); urlComponents?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: "movies"), URLQueryItem(name: "Genre", value: "#Action")]; guard let url = urlComponents?.url else { return }`

Comment: @Larme, Thank you. I wanted to pass the query param as Custom String

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `#` character is the separator for the `fragment` of the URL.

The most reliable way to build an URL with multiple components is `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem`, the encoding is free

```
func searchMovies(with parameters: [String:String]) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://search.movies.local/list.html")!
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }
    if !queryItems.isEmpty { urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems }
    print("URL: ", urlComponents.url) // https://search.movies.local/list.html?genre=%23action&name=%23movie
}


searchMovies(with: ["name":"#movie","genre":"#action"])
```

---

Or

```
func searchMovies(by query: String?) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://search.movies.local/list.html")!
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
    if let queryString = query {
        let queryPairs = queryString.components(separatedBy: "&")
        for aPair in queryPairs {
            let keyValue = aPair.components(separatedBy: "=")
            if keyValue.count != 2 { continue }
            queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: keyValue[0], value: keyValue[1]))
        }
        if !queryItems.isEmpty { urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems }
    }
    print("URL: ", urlComponents.url) // https://search.movies.local/list.html?genre=%23action&name=%23movie
}

searchMovies(by: "name=#movies&Genre=#Action")
```

Comment: `urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems` => `urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems.isEmpty ? nil : queryItems` else, it will add a `?` at the end of the URL which might usually not be the desired output.

Comment: Good answer. Needless to say, the first approach is preferable, because the former technique will fail if the manually built string had a `&` in it (e.g. searching for a title like "Bonnie & Clyde").